# CoProfile Visibility Setting fields

Tags: standard-objects

Which objects that are being exhibited in Profile Visibility below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, these all fields reside on User object.

For example, *Photo visibility* is stored in standard field `UserPreferencesShowProfilePicToGuestUsers`. If this is false, means photo is available to members only. And on user interface, you would see "Members" as selected. Default value of this field is false. Now, If you want to make Photo available for public then check the box `UserPreferencesShowProfilePicToGuestUsers` to true.

Likewise other given fields visibility is controlled based on standard boolean fields. It's really well explained here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_contact_info_visibility.htm&type=5